# Is there anyway to get correct value for each rows in a matrix table?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure, datamodel

I have created a matrix table with rows gowdown(gowdown mapping),product group(product group mapping) and stockitem(allstock). The columns are closing quantity,sales amount,quantity sold and requirement.Here i am getting the correct value for gowdown and product group for each rows. but for some rows(shop) the requirement value is showing the same for all the stockitem. requirement isa measure created in re-order table. gowdown mapping and product group mapping have an active relationship between reorder table. the relationship with stockitem table is inactive.
How can I get the correct value for the requirement?
Below is the requirement measure:

Requirement = CALCULATE('Sales report'[Avg Sales Qty in reorder period])+SUM(ATReorderReportGrpCmpODBCMain[$MinimumDisplayQuantity])-SUM(AllStockSummaryBatchGrpODBC[$ClosingQty])-SUM(ATSCTotalTransitItemWiseCollODBC[TransitQty])-SUM(CMPSPurchaseOrderVchCollMain[Latest Open PO Qty])
[note:I have used the same requirement for another matrix table with rows gowodwn,product group and supplier(product group mapping table) it return the correct value for every rows]

i would like to know what is thereason forthe error.Is it because of the relationshipor Dax function.How can i resolve it.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output for better understanding.